# Обход и удаление обработчиков события click

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery, веб-программирование

Есть код, вешающий обработчик события на элемент

```js
element.addEventListener( 'click', clickHandler );
```

Каким образом можно осуществить обход и удаление обработчиков события click? Я имею ввиду, что необходимо удалить некоторые обработчики одного события (задаваемые некоторым образом) с одного элемента - например, необходимо удалить все обработчики события кроме одного.

Comment: какой обход? вокруг чего? что мешает написать removeEventListener?

Comment: Наверное, стоит уточнить: вам нужно удалить обработчики одного события с одного элемента или со всех элементов, у которых есть такие обработчики.

Answer (score 0):

Предполагаю, вы имели ввиду removeEventListener

```
div.addEventListener('click', listener, false);
div.removeEventListener('click', listener, false);
```

Comment: Значение третьего аргумента, кстати, и так по умолчанию false.

Comment: @Crus  я уточнил вопрос.

Comment: @developer.fron а вы можете осуществить обход и удалить через `removeEventListener` все ненужные обработчики, не удаляя нужные?

Comment: @br3t а как осуществить обход - поочередное обращение к обработчикам?